# API Route: Edit return 404 not found

Tags: laravel

I have an API that when performing a request on the online server returns not foud. When I do the same test on localhost, I have expected return.

Result the rout list:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

When I make the same request on localhost:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: what returns the 404, laravel or the webserver directly? what url on the server are you trying to hit?

Comment: When accessing: mydomain.com/api/member/edit/39, I have the return not foud. When accessing localHost / api / member / edit / 39, I get the expected response.

Comment: Do you have the same database? Does member with id 39 exist?

Comment: Look at the result of the request in one of the question images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me there will be any of the following situation -

- You will need to check whether you have cache the routing or not. So follow the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#route-caching)
- Or as per we see your api working with the localhost with 8000 port So check with public route. Like - mydomain.com/public/api/member/edit/39 or create virtual host on server before using API. (This arise another question is the api/members API working on your domain?)

Comment: Other requests in the API work. Only this /api/member/edit that returns not found on server

Comment: Have you cache the routing or not? And Is the another GET type request working on your server.